# New VPS - Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: ssh, oracle, vps

I created an Oracle VM with Ubuntu, during which, I generated an ssh key pair, which I uploaded to Oracle.

This key allows me to login to the default user, and everything works fine.

I added however a new user, copied over the public key to the new authorized_keys in the new profile, but am unable to log in with my user. I actually changed the configurations in sshd to only allow the default user, and my own, but still to now success. I get a Permission denied (publickey) error.

I tried to generate a new keypair just for this custom user, and replaced the key in authorized_keys, and that didn't work either.

Any suggestions?

Please find the verbose output of my connection here: https://pastebin.com/JV3SABjh

Answer (score 0):

After carefully verifying all permissions settings (yes, I know), I verified that I messed it up, by changing the ownership of authorized_keys to root. Changing those permissions to the correct user, fixed that issue.

Note to self, always ensure .ssh and authorized_keys belong to the user you want to log in to, the folder is 0700 and the file 0600!